# QStackedWidget equivalent for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, qt

I am porting a small qt app to java and i was wondering if java swing has an equivalent to Qt's QStackedWidget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`QStackedWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html)?

> The `QStackedWidget` class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time..

See [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  :)